# Right name to these arrays

Tags: jquery, arrays

I would like to know what is the right names for these 2 arrays:

```
//html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>

// javascript/jquery
var all = $('div');
console.log(all);         //array 1
console.log(all.get());   //array 2
```

Array 1 - Array of objects?
Array 2 - Array of elements?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X5uyr/) (if needed)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second one is an array of DOM elements, yes. But the first one is a jQuery object. It mimicks an array, and acts as a wrapper for the collection of elements, enabling you to call jQuery methods (e.g. `.css()`) on a set of elements at once, on a single line.

Comment: Ok, more clear now. I had tried some array methods in the " jQuery object" without success. Now I understand is not an array...

Comment: It's not an array, so you can't use the array methods directly. But since it's array-like, you can still use most of them indirectly. For example, `Array.prototype.pop.call($('div'))` will pop from the jQuery object.

Answer (score 1):

Array 1

This is a jQuery wrapped array.  jQuery bundles up the DOM elements you found into an array but they have added a few properties and functions to the array for convenience in manipulating the array further

Array 2

When you call .get() you are getting an array that has ONLY the DOM elements.  You won't be able to call jQuery functions on this array like .find(), etc.